# html sending parameters to function from id

Tags: javascript, html, function-parameter

I'm an absolute beginner and tried to find similar questions but couldn't. Apologies if this has been answered previously.
In my assignment we need to create a form with 2 text fields and 1 button. The fields are for height and width and the idea is that `onclick` on the button will send the 2 parameters to a function that will change the height + width attributes for a photo. I know I'm doing something wrong because the picture simply disappears. Ideas? Thanks!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            function borderResize(height1, width1)
            {
                document.getElementById('Amos').height = height1;
                document.getElementById('Amos').width = width1;
            }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <img src="Amos.jpg" id="Amos" />
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="Height" />
            <input type="text" id="width" placeholder="Width" />
            <input type="button" value="click!" onclick="borderResize('height.value', 'width.value')"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
onclick="borderResize('height.value', 'width.value')"
```

in means that on click `borderResize` function will be invoked with two string arguments, literally strings "height.value" and "width.value". In your case you want something like this

```
onclick="borderResize(document.getElementById('height').value, document.getElementById('width').value)"
```

In above case you are selecting element from DOM using [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)  method and then read its value property.

Comment: Tried it. Chrome debugger: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string"

Comment: Sorry, I left extra quote in the code. Updated answer. Try it again.

Comment: Now I get: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: Yes, there was one more typo. Fixed too.

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks for an informative answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should learn to use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), I would recommend you not to use ugly inline click handler.

> The EventTarget.addEventListener() method registers the specified listener on the EventTarget it's called on.

Here is an example with your code.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', borderResize, true);
}

function borderResize() {
  document.getElementById('Amos').height = document.getElementById('height').value;
  document.getElementById('Amos').width = document.getElementById('width').value;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/11034289_10152822971918167_2916173497205137007_n.jpg?oh=71de7a46a75a946cf1d76e5ab10c1cdc&oe=55889977&__gda__=1434173455_6127f174627ed6014c84e562f47bc44c" id="Amos" />

<input type="text" id="height" placeholder="Height" />
<input type="text" id="width" placeholder="Width" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="click!" />
```

---

However as for your immediate problem you can use

```
onclick="borderResize(document.getElementById('height').value, document.getElementById('width').value)"
```

Comment: We cannot yet use things we haven't learned in class. It's stupid but that's how it is. I'll use the last line of code. Thanks!
EDIT: tried it. chrome debugger now writes: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="borderResize('height.value', 'width.value')"
```

here you pass to borderResize strings: 'height.value', 'width.value'.
You may get value of input from function:

```
function borderResize(height1, width1)
{
    document.getElementById('Amos').height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    document.getElementById('Amos').width = document.getElementById('width').value;
}
```

Comment: Well... doesn't your solution simply ignore the passed parameters?